# Is there a key based auth version of PHP's ftp_login()?

Tags: php, ftp, sftp

I am trying to change an old piece of code that uses `ftp_login()` with a username and password to instead use an ssh key I have installed on the server.

I've found phpseclib which seems to be able to do that, but it requires I rewrite the entire section of code (e.g. `ftp_put()` would have to become `$sftp->put()`) and install that library. Ideally I would only need to replace `ftp_login()` and nothing would need to be installed.

I haven't come across anything like that in my research, but that hardly means it doesn't exist. Does anyone know of a key based alternative to `ftp_login()` that isn't phpseclib?

Comment: Trying to use a key-based-auth over ftp (encryption piece over unencrypted protocol) seems a little bit odd. Maybe you should really consider to rewrite it to sftp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP `ftp_*` functions implement FTP protocol. A public key authentication is used with SFTP protocol (based on SSH).

The SFTP is a completely different protocol than the FTP. So there's absolutely no way, you can use the `ftp_*` functions for the SFTP (let alone for the public key authentication).

For the SFTP (*even without the public key authentication*), you have to use a different set of functions, like phpseclib or PHP SSH2. And that indeed means a complete rewrite of the code.